# Is this kind of convex closed always has non-empty interior?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

First of all, my apologies for my lack of knowledge in Latex. Please feel free to ask questions about my wording.

Q: Let $C$ be a closed convex set in a vector space $X$ such that $C + B(X)$ always contains a closed ball centred at $0$ with radius ($1+ \epsilon$) (for some positive $\epsilon$). Now does it always follow that the interior of $C$ is always non-empty?

In $F^n$ (for some field $F$), this is always because things in the space is just too well-behaved. Then I tried the following space:

This space consists of all the mapping $f$ from $N$ to $C$ where for all the functions, there exists an integer $m$ such that $f(n) = 0$ for all $n\geq m$. This is a Banach space under the infinity norm. However, I failed to find out what an open set look like in this space so I did not proceed further.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: The space of finite sequences, which is mentioned in the last paragraph, is **not** a Banach space.

Comment: Ah .... yes. Thank you for your correction.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is normed and $0\in C$ this goes as follows: From the assumption you get for the ball $B(0,1)$ around $0$ with radius $1$ that $B(0,1)\subseteq \frac 1r C + B(0,\frac 1r)$. Iterating this you get for all $n$ that 
$$
B(0,1)\subseteq \frac 1r C +\frac {1}{r^2}C + \cdots \frac{1}{r^n}C + B(0,\frac{1}{r^{n}}).$$
(EDIT: Corrected the radius from $\frac{1}{r^{n+1}}$ to $\frac{1}{r^{n}}$.) Using convexity and $0\in C$ the *Minkowski sum* is contained in 
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{r^k}\right) C = \frac{1}{r-1} C.$$

Since $C$ is closed this shows that $C$ contains the ball $B(0,r-1)$.

Comment: Hello, Jochen:
  Could you further explain why you can iterate what you did in the second line? I can not really understand how you get multiple Cs there. The rest of the proofs is fine.
  Also, you provided a case where C contains an interior, which is helpful for me but probably not enough to answer the question. It seems reasonable to have 0 in C because in R^n it has to. However, for a more general C, does it contain an interior?

Comment: Write $B(0,\frac 1r)=\frac 1r B(0,1)$ and use the inclusion $B(0,1)\subseteq \frac 1r C + \frac 1r B(0,1)$ twice to obtain $B(0,1) \subseteq \frac 1r C + \frac{1}{r^2} C + \frac{1}{r^2}B(0,1)$. Inductively you get $B(0,1) \subseteq \frac 1r C + \frac{1}{r^2} C + \cdots \frac{1}{r^n} C +\frac{1}{r^n}B(0,1)$.

Comment: Got it now. Really thank you for your answer !